# probability of running out of gas

Tags: probability, statistics

So this is a two part question, but I figured out part B and I thought I had part A but it isn't working. Also, sorry if my formatting is not up to par, if anyone can reformat it if it looks bad, I'll approve it.

A gas station owner knows from experience that the average amount of gas per sale is **11.2 gallons** and the standard deviation is **5.1 gallons**. Suppose there will be **157 customers tomorrow**. He has **1840 gallons** of gas available.

A. What is the probability that he will run out of gas tomorrow? (Hint: if the total gas sold to the 157 customers is more than 1840 gallons, what can you say about the average amount sold to this group?)

Here's what I tried, I figured this was a normal cdf so I plugged it into my calculator with the following dimensions, for the lower it was -infinity, for the upper it was 1840, for mu I had 157*11.2 and for sigma i had 157*5.1. I ended up getting .5405863302 from which I subtracted 1 by to get 0.4594136698 and this is apparently not the correct answer. However, I followed the same format for part B and got the correct answer so I'm at a loss here as to what my dimensions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has standard deviation $s$, then $nX$ has standard deviation $\sqrt{n}s$, not $ns$.

This is because we have $Var(nX)=nVar(X)$

Comment: What was the question in $B$ and how did you answer it ?

Comment: The question in B was B. Supposing that the distribution of gas per sale is normal, what is the probability that the next customer buys more than 11.5 gallons? and I answered it by using a normal CDF on my calculator but the lower limit was -infinity, the upper 11.5, mu was 11.2 and sigma was 5.1. The answer was 1 - this which came out to be .4765462631

Comment: Try $A$ with $sigma=\sqrt{157}\cdot 5.1$. Is the result correct ?

Comment: YES! Thank you! How come it was sqrt(157) instead of just 157?

Comment: See my answer above.